# How I make brackets in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, brackets

How I make this brackets and the formula below in LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/epu70d310xdr188/Captura%20de%20ecr%C3%A3%202016-03-29%2C%20%C3%A0s%2023.36.20.png?dl=0

Comment: Use two `cases`  environments.

Answer (score 5):

Since `array`s are vertically centred, set two next to one another:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}% Remove inter-column gap
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}% Space out equations
  \left\{\begin{array}{ r l }
    \sum F_x & {}= m \times a_n \\
    \sum F_y & {}= m \times a_t
  \end{array}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
  \quad\leftrightarrow\quad
  \left\{\begin{array}{ r l }
    T - m g \cos\theta & {}= m \times a_n \\
      - m g \sin\theta & {}= m \times a_t
  \end{array}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{cases}
    \Sigma F_\mathrm{x} = m \times a_n \\
    \Sigma F_\mathrm{y} = m \times a_t
\end{cases}
\leftrightarrow \ \
\begin{cases}\!
    \begin{aligned}
        T - mg\cos\theta  &= m \times a_n \\
        {}- mg\sin\theta  &= m \times a_t
    \end{aligned}
\end{cases}
\]    

\[
\left\{\!
\begin{aligned}
    \Sigma F_\mathrm{x} &= m \times a_n \\
    \Sigma F_\mathrm{y} &= m \times a_t
\end{aligned}\right. \ \
\leftrightarrow \ \
\left\{\!
\begin{aligned}
    T - mg\cos\theta  &= m \times a_n \\
    {}- mg\sin\theta  &= m \times a_t
\end{aligned}\right.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: While this gets the desired affect, I disagree semantically with the use of the cases environment. There aren't any "cases" in the equation.  Why not `\left\{\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}\right.`?

Comment: `aligned` should be prepended with `\!` or may be with `etoolbox` `\AtBeginEnvironment{aligned}{\!}`.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang  - Good point, I added that option too.